# Where clauses are not corresponding to what is referenced in the query in Ecto.Query

Tags: elixir, ecto

Here is the original `Ecto.Query`

```
def by_id(user_id, company_id, asset_id) do

        # section 1
        from a in Asset,

        # section 2
        join: acl in AccessList, on: acl.asset_id == a.id, 
        join: c in Company, on: acl.company_id == c.id,
        join: u in User, on: acl.user_id == u.id, 

        # section 3
        where: u.id == ^user_id and c.id == ^company_id

        # section 4 
        and a.id == ^asset_id,
        # section 5
        select: %{ 
            asset_name: a.asset_name, 
            asset_id: a.id,
            inserted_at: a.inserted_at 
            }, 

        # section 6
        group_by: a.id,

        # section 6 
        order_by: a.id

    end
```

**Refactored:**

```
 def by_query do
        from a in Asset
    end

    def by_join(query) do
        from a in query,
        join: acl in AccessList, on: acl.asset_id == a.id,
        join: c in Company, on: acl.company_id == c.id,
        join: u in User, on: acl.user_id == u.id
    end

    def by_where_user(query, user_id) do
        query = from q in query
        query
        |> where([u], u.id == ^user_id) 
    end

    def by_where_company(query, company_id) do
        query = from q in query
        query
        |> where([c], c.id == ^company_id) 
    end

    def by_where_asset(query, asset_id) do
        query = from q in query
        query
        |> where([a], a.id == ^asset_id)
    end

    def by_select(query) do
        from a in query,
        select: %{ 
            asset_name: a.asset_name, 
            asset_id: a.id,
            inserted_at: a.inserted_at 
        },
        group_by: a.id, 
        order_by: a.id
    end
```

Then I connected then like this:

```
  query = by_query
       |> by_join
       |> by_where_user(user_id)
       |> by_where_company(company_id)
       |> by_where_asset(asset_id)
       |> by_select
```

Now it doesn't work.

The generated query is different, I can see the issue is with the `where` clauses.

```
    SELECT a0."asset_name", a0."id", a0."inserted_at" 
FROM "assets" AS a0 
INNER JOIN "access_lists" AS a1 ON a1."asset_id" = a0."id" 
INNER JOIN "companies" AS c2 ON a1."company_id" = c2."id" 
INNER JOIN "users" AS u3 ON a1."user_id" = u3."id" 
WHERE (a0."id" = $1) 
AND (a0."id" = $2) 
AND (a0."id" = $3) 
GROUP BY a0."id" 
ORDER BY a0."id" [3349, 1, 5]
```

`Where` should be `a0`, `c2` and `u3`

Here is based on: 
https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#module-query-bindings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with three `by_where_*` clauses. There is no state, hence `Ecto` has no chance to remember how the selects were called in other functions. The easiest way to handle it would be to use the other association end:

```
def by_where_user(query, user_id) do
    from q in query
    |> where([result], result.user_id == ^user_id) 
end

def by_where_company(query, company_id) do
    from q in query
    |> where([result], result.company_id == ^company_id) 
end

def by_where_asset(query, asset_id) do
    from q in query
    |> where([result], result.asset_id == ^asset_id)
end
```

Comment: So based on what you have mentioned I can't start from asset and comes in to the join table. I need to start from the join as it has `user_id`, `company_id` and `asset_id` which is fine, just different way of looking at the same problem. `Select` needs to be rewritten then to simply call the `Asset` and filter it based on the result of the composed query. thank you for your help.